# How to align left and right in HTML so that part of one element slips under another as the screen narrows?

Tags: html, css

At the moment two of my columns are as follows. They work fine when the screen width is above 900px.

[image]

How can I allow the bottom element in column 3 to slip under the element in column 2 when the screen narrows to about 800px, so as to retain the graphical concept? I am after a solution using pure HTML and CSS, no JS, giving something like this:

[image]

```css
#col3 {
  float: left;
  width: 60px;
}

#col4 {
  font-size: 80%;
  display: inline;
  float: right;
  text-align: right;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 0 20px 0 0;
}

.col4-mitem {
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding-left: 20px;
  font-size: 80%;
}

.col4-mitem a:link,
a:visited {
  color: #000;
  text-decoration: none;
  border-bottom: 0;
}

.col4-mitem a:hover,
a:active {
  color: #f00;
}

#stext-input {
  border: solid 1px;
  border-right: none;
  font-size: 80%;
  float: left;
  height: 14px;
  padding-left: 5px;
  width: 180px;
}
```

```html
<div id="col3">
  <select class="select-box" id="form">
  <option value="">Browse past issues</option>
  <option value="http://foobar.com/1.html">Issue 7</option>
  <option value="http://foobar.com/2.html">Issue 8</option>
  <option value="http://foobar.com/3.html">Issue 9</option>
  <option value="http://foobar.com/4.html">Issue 10</option>
  </select>
</div>
<!--close col3-->
<div id="col4">
  <span class="col4-item"><a href="#1">link 1</a></span>
  <span class="col4-item"><a href="#2">link 2</a></span>
  <br>
  <form method="get" id="search" action="http://duckduckgo.com/">
    <input type="hidden" name="sites" value="foobar.com" />
    <input type="hidden" name="k8" value="#f00" />
    <input type="hidden" name="k9" value="#00f" />
    <input type="hidden" name="kaa" value="#808" />
    <input type="hidden" name="ks" value="m" />
    <input type="hidden" name="kt" value="a" />
    <input type="hidden" name="ka" value="a" />
    <input type="hidden" name="k1" value="-1" />
    <input type="text" name="q" id="stext-input" placeholder="Search...">
    <input id="yes" type="image" src="yes.png">
  </form>
  <br>
  <div class="strap-line">strap line strap line strap line strap line strap line </div>
</div>
<!--close col4-->
```

Comment: make use of @media Queries

Comment: Giving an answer based on your existing source would be easier if your source had something to do with your question.

Comment: @MrLister - I have amended the source extract pasted here now. I was trying to get it down to the bare minimum.

Comment: Please make a plunker with what you have. At first glance it seems to me, you must use media query and change widths, floats etc for specific screens.

Comment: @ChandraShekhar - But how? I realise the solution will probably involve having a single column in place of the two shown, but I'm unclear of what to do after combining the columns to get "browse past issues" to the left of the column and the other three elements to end at the right of the page.

Comment: Sorry - what is a plunker?